# Minio access policy

Tags: react-native, amazon-iam, minio

I'm trying to read an image on my react-native app.
How can i configure the access policy to allow only app mobile to read images on `<Image />`    ?

My minio access policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": [
                        "com.myapp" // applicationId on android
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In my react-native App.js

```
<Image 
   source={{uri: "http://xxxx/my-bucket/test.png"}}
   onError={(e)=>console.log(e.nativeEvent.error)} 
/>
```

In console
`Unexpected HTTP code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=http://xxxx/my-bucket/test.png}`

Comment: First thing to check: is actually the "UserAgent" header that your App sends?  What happens if your remove the `aws:UserAgent` constraint from your Bucket Policy?

Comment: I found `UserAgent` but it is different of my applicationId

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. The `aws:UserAgent` condition key evaluates to the value of the "user-agent" HTTP header in the request; if your App is sending some other value, then you'll need to either change your Bucket Policy or your App.  Please keep in mind that this is *not* strong authentication: anyone who knows or guesses your user-agent header can access your data.

Comment: That's why I want to put a policy, which only allows my android application

Comment: If you want to ensure that only your App can access your data, then you need to somehow authenticate it to AWS.  The best strategy is probably to authenticate it to something else with federation set up with AWS Cognito; that will get you temporary AWS creds that you can use to read from S3.